# redirection help and browser recognization of the URL

Tags: asp.net

I got a email from a website which contain a scrambled URL which redirects to forget password page? and my question is how the scrambled url link takes to a specific page?

Ex:-if you see the link of yahoo.com forget password it would like

```
www.yahoo.com/gbvkjwekuy664vbhfekjb22gbun
```

what is this "`gbvkjwekuy664vbhfekjb22gbun`" and how can we go to a specific page with these?,
how can the browser understand this kind of things for redirections?

Answer (score 0):

When you request for reset password, you MUST have to provide any means of your `identity`, e.g: Email Address, Username, etc. How this procedures works is (roughly):

- When you request for password, they take your identity, and generate some sort of identifier, such as `gbvkjwekuy664vbhfekjb22gbun`, map it to your identity (Email Address, Username, whatever), and save it to their DB.
- When you receive Email from them, they also give you a link to reset password. in that link, they append that generated identifier, so that they can identify you, when you continue your procedure of resetting password.

so, that generated identifier is nothing more than to identify the the person (through incoming request), requesting to continue the reset password procedure. This way, they make sure that you are the actual owner of the associated account (Email). because your request proves your identity.

Comment: you mean generating hash or encrypted format of our ID such as Email or any other and pass it in "Query String" and accepting the hash in the "query string" and match it with the existing data base record of the stored one and further proceedings are done

Comment: @TARUNKUMARCHINTA Yes. but we can not be sure, if it's `HASH` of our ID or something. because every one has their own logic/implementation. What we only know is, `it's an identifier, that coresponds to your password recovery request.` to make sure, it's really 'YOU', proceeding your request

Comment: @TARUNKUMARCHINTA if you have got the answer to your question, consider accepting/voting the answer. Welcome to StackOverflow world :)